# WP_Query, create html structure

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a page here to illustrate my question

http://www.ttmt.org.uk.

The first grid is hard coded using the html structure I want - div's to contain each row and then div's inside that to contain each block.

My problem is how do I create this structure in a WP_Query.

If I output the row in the WP_Query it will give me 1 block in each row. I want three blocks in each row.

Do I need some sort of loop within a loop?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 5</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 6</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 7</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 8</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p>Post 9</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="container two">

        <h3>With WP_Query</h3>

        <?php
            $grid_args  = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order'
            );

            $grid_loop = new WP_Query($grid_args);

            if($grid_loop->have_posts()):
                while($grid_loop->have_posts()):
                    $grid_loop->the_post();

        ?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 box">
                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
            endwhile;
            endif;
        ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the trick "when starts a new row?" yourself.

While in the loop you can count the col index. If it reaches 3 (use modulo so you can avoid resetting the index) then start a new row.

Something like that (I didn't test it):

```
<?php
$grid_loop = new WP_Query($grid_args);

$col = 0;
if($grid_loop->have_posts()):

    while($grid_loop->have_posts()):
?>
        <?php if($col % 3 == 0) ?>
          <div class="row"><!-- start row -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="col-xs-3 box">
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </div>

        <?php if($col % 3 == 2) ?>
          </div><!-- end row -->
        <?php endif; ?>

<?php
        $col++;
    endwhile;
?>
   <?php if($col % 3 != 0) ?>
       </div><!-- close row if it is still open -->
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php
endif;
?>
```